# Firebase Cloud Messaging : How to send push notification to users on specific day after install?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send push notifications using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) to users on a specific day after install.

For instance, After install, I want to send push notifications on Day 0, 1, 2... etc. to the users.

Please help me how can I achieve this with Firebase?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a cloud function in order to deliver to the users the notification.

First, you will need to get the users [FirebaseInstanceId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId) , which will be used later to send notifications to these users.

> Firebase Instance ID provides a unique identifier for each app
>   instance and a mechanism to authenticate and authorize actions
>   (example: sending FCM messages).

Then, you will need to push some data to the user who opened your app, you can sign in the user with any authentication method that provides Firebase

See [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/?gclid=CjwKCAiAp5nyBRABEiwApTwjXisUTaz87ZPqvtE_SjXvGX6Bg18K5PDLGd9SDIgJGBeTqBXYarqQmxoCX8oQAvD_BwE)

After the user has logged in, you can push to the user the times it opened your app, this will be code in your `onCreate()` which will update a value in that user node incrementing the total count when the user opens the app.

After that you will need to store the first time the user logs in timestamp, and then the logout timestamp.

The logout timestamp can be when the user exits your app and `onDestroy()` is hit, then you can compare the first time the user signed in and the last time the user has been active.

If this difference is greater than 24 hs and the user has a counter greater than 5 (the times the user visited in `onCreate()` ) you can run a cloud function with that user token and schedule a notification

see [Schedule functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)

The functions should be a simple get to the users node, you can get all the users data and then compare the timestamps and the times the user opened the app, if that criteria matchs your case, get the user instance ID and send a notification to that user scheduled